# Proving that for any odd number $n$ there exists $i$ such that $2^i \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Tags: number-theory

Is there any theorem that proves the following?

> For any odd number $n$, there exits an $i$ such that
>
> $$2^i \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Let $n$ be your odd number. Take $i = \phi (n)$.

Since $\gcd (n,2)=1$, $2^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n$.